# Windows CMD: List files in dir & subdir WITHOUT given extensions

Tags: windows, file, list, shell, command-line

I'd like to recursively search a directory and find files, which have NOT a certain extension, or precisely, which have NOT a certain set of extensions.

**Sketch: find in "dir" all files without "ext1", "ext2", "ext3" and print results to .txt**

I tried around several hours with DIR and ATTRIB, but unfortunately without bigger success.

Your consideration is highly regarded! Thanks.

Comment: Probably easier if you install cygwin and use e.g. `find`.

Comment: Install cygwin?! Are you crazy, that's a seriously over the top solution to a trivial problem. If you need more tools then some native ones (e.g. GnuWin32) would be more to the point.  This is a one liner in grep for example. And as LittleBobbyTables has pointed out it can be done natively by the cmd interpreter.

Comment: @David: Not natively, but with the tools available nearly everywhere (`findstr` isn't a built-in command of `cmd`, while `dir` is). Agreed on the craziness of bringing cygwin into this, though.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
dir /b /s /a-d | findstr /vi ".ext1$ .ext2$ .ext3$"
```

The `/a-d` switch excludes directories, giving you only files.  The `findstr` parameter lets you search the files for strings, and the `/vi` switch indicates to exclude files containing the next parameter, the search being case insensitive.

As Joey pointed out, the `$` is necessary to indicate end of the line.

Comment: +1 for a nice and elegant solution. Caution to the user, though: If you have Unicode file names that cannot be represented in the selected OEM character set *and* you have Raster fonts enabled in `cmd`, then this will mangle the file names and you cannot do anything with them.

Comment: Another side note: This won't filter the extensions, but substrings of the file names. So if you have a file named `foo.ext1.bar` it will get filtered out too.

Comment: that absolutely works like a charm. exactly the expression i was looking for. thx so much.

Comment: @Joey: can i prevent the substring issue by cascading findstr?       eg: dir /b /s /a-d | findstr /vi ".ext1" | findstr /vi ".ext2"

Comment: @Joey -- d'oh, forgot the $ signs.  I've updated the query so it should only exclude files ending with the extension.

Comment: DapperDan: Add the `/e` switch and it should work (as far as my tests go).

Comment: @Joey -- worked for me just fine without the `/R` switch, but the `/E` probably is more consistent.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Indeed, it appears to work without. That's ... interesting (and undocumented). As for `/E` ... I *think* that came with a more recent version of Windows and isn't available in ancient ones. Although XP might already have it.

Comment: exact same results :) you guys are great. helped me alot! thx